# Why is it not possible to modify the value at the next addresses after an address that is passed by reference as const in a function?

Tags: c, pointers, reference, constants, memory-address

I have the following code and I am confused why is it now working:

```
#include<stdio.h>

void modif(const int *p)
{

  *(p+1)=5;
}

int main()
{
  int a=1;
  printf("\n%d",a);
  modif(&a);
  printf("\n%d",a);


  return 0;
}
```

The error I am getting is this one:

```
main.c: In function 'modif':
main.c:6:9: error: assignment of read-only location '*(p + 4)'
   *(p+1)=5;
         ^

exit status 1
```

In my opinion the address next to p should be modifiable. I have tried to modify the values at addresses that were further away and the result was the same.

When using "const" keyword before a parameter passed by reference what is the first address that is actually modifiable?

Comment: You are invoking undefined behaviour. Do not access memory that you do not own.

Comment: No, `p` is a const pointer. So you may dereference it only for reading, not for writing. You could write `int foo = *(p+1);`, but that's UB in your case because you are reading memory you don't own.

Comment: An argument like `const int *p` could mean that `p` is pointing to a single constant integer. Or it could be pointing to the *first element of an array* of constant integers. The compiler doesn't really know which it is.

Comment: Nothing can be modified using `p` (short of casting away the `const`).   `p` is a pointer to a `const int`.   So is `p + i` where `i` is any integral value.

Comment: By the way, what is it you attempt to do? What is the problem that lead you to ask this question? Perhaps you should ask about that problem instead?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I am writing code to learn the behavior of C compilers in different situations. The only purpose of this code is exploring and educating myself.

Comment: @Peter How do you cast away a const?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude "Or it could be pointing to the first element of an array of constant integers. The compiler doesn't really know which it is." - Thanks. This actually makes a lot of sense. I understand now why the authors of C chose to implement this behavior.

Answer (score 1):

*'In my opinion the address next to p should be modifiable'*

Authors of C language have opposite opinion. And it's *their* opinion which counts.

The C semantics allows you to perform a so-called pointer arithmetics, which includes adding and subtracting integers to/from typed pointers. The pointer value resulting from such operation points to an element of *the same array*, respective number of items farther or earlier in the array.

However the `const` modifier applies to the whole array (despite its size being not specified), so it does not vanish in such operation. If it did, you could just do `*((p+1)-1)` to access a `*p` variable without the `const` restriction!

Answer (score 1):

This statement

```
  *(p+1)=5;
```

is problematic for a couple of reasons.

`p` is `const`-qualified. So that's the reason for the error you get.
You violate the promise you made to the compiler (that you wouldn't modify the object pointed to by `p`).

*If* you didn't have the `const` qualifier, it's still wrong.
Because the object that `p` points to is a single `int`, so dereferencing `p+1` is [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).
Note that evaluating `p+1` is fine even if `p` points to a single `int` object. It's allowed per [C11, 6.5.6/9](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.6p9).
But dereferencing it is not valid.

If there's a valid object at `p + 1` (provided that object itself is mutable - otherwise, this will be undefined behaviour), you could cast away the `const` in `modif()` and legally modify it. For example, the below is valid (but not something I recommend - if you want `modif` to be able to modify `a`'s contents, it doesn't make sense to qualify `p` with `const` here).

```
#include<stdio.h>

void modif(const int *p)
{
  int *q = (int*)p;
  *(q+1)=5;
}

int main()
{
  int a[2] = {0};
  modif(a);
  printf("\n%d, %d",a[0], a[1]);

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're just passing a pointer which in C may point to an arbitrarily sized array of objects -- size `1` for a single object is just one possible case. It's your job as a programmer to find means how the function knows how many objects there are.

If the pointer is a pointer to a `const`, this means the whole array is immutable.

In your code, your pointer only points to a single object, so accessing the non-existing object at index `1` is just *undefined behavior*. If this object *would* exist, would you expect it to be modifyable through a const pointer? Of course not ...

Comment: Surprisingly, there is no undefined behavior in this program ...because there is actually no behavior in it at all. There would be if it could be compiled and run - but as we can see it does not compile... ;)